# How can you link to a font file that is not in your public folder in Meteor?

Tags: fonts, meteor

I have a couple of non-free, licensed fonts that I would like to use in my Meteor application. However, it seems like the only way to link to a font file in my css file is by putting the font file in the /public folder. This is undesirable, as this exposes the font files to the general public.

How can I include a font file without making it accessible to the general web?

Comment: what are other ways of including the font on a webpage w/o exposing it to the general web? Is it done with ajax requests from the page?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question: it's fundamentally impossible to allow general website users to view fonts on your website without allowing them to download the font files. Did you mean you only want to use the font files for logged in users?